# Trying to perform 2D Cross correlation on 2 images without using Matlab/Numpy/etc

Tags: c#, image-processing, signal-processing, fft, cross-correlation

I am trying to perform Cross Correlation on these 2 images in C#: 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2bWt.png), [Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE9oz.png) 
Matlab says the result is supposed to look like: [Matlab result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3zLj.jpg) 
But this is my result: [My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7EiB.jpg) 
Here is my Cross Correlation function:

```
public static Signal2D CrossCorrelation2D(Signal2D signal, Signal2D pulse) {
    return InverseFFT2D(FFT2D(signal) * FFT2D(pulse).GetConjugate());
}
```

Here is my FFT2D:

```
public static Signal2D FFT2D(Signal2D signal) {
    Signal2D result = new Signal2D(signal.Height, signal.Width);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Height; i++)
        result[i] = new ComplexNumber[signal[i].Length];
    //rows
    for (int n = 0; n < signal.Height; n++) {
        result[n] = FFT(signal[n]);
    }
    //columns
    for (int i = 0; i < signal[0].Length; i++) {
        ComplexNumber[] col = new ComplexNumber[signal.Height];
        for (int j = 0; j < col.Length; j++) {
            col[j] = result[j][i];
        }
        col = FFT(col);
        for (int j = 0; j < col.Length; j++) {
            result[j][i] = col[j];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is my FFT:

```
public static Signal FFT(Signal signal) {
    int N = signal.Length;
    if (N == 1)
        return signal;
    if ((N & (N - 1)) != 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("signal length must be a power of 2");
    Signal evenArr = new Signal(N / 2);
    Signal oddArr = new Signal(N / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
        evenArr[i] = signal[2 * i];
    }
    evenArr = FFT(evenArr);
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++) {
        oddArr[i] = signal[2 * i + 1];
    }
    oddArr = FFT(oddArr);
    Signal result = new Signal(N);
    for (int k = 0; k < N / 2; k++) {
        double w = -2.0 * k * Math.PI / N;
        ComplexNumber wk = new ComplexNumber(Math.Cos(w), Math.Sin(w));
        ComplexNumber even = evenArr[k];
        ComplexNumber odd = oddArr[k];
        result[k] = even + (wk * odd);
        result[k + N / 2] = even - (wk * odd);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is my Signal multiplication (using pointwise multiplication):

```
public static Signal2D operator* (Signal2D a, Signal2D b) {
    if (a.Height != b.Height || a.Width != b.Width)
        throw new ArgumentException("Sizes must be equal");
    Signal2D result = new Signal2D(a.Height, a.Width);
    for (int y = 0; y < a.Height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < a.Width; x++) {
            result[y][x] = a[y][x] * b[y][x];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: I left the matlab image at the original size of 1023 by 1023 and overlayed my result. It looks like I may already be at the result, I am just not sure how Matlab pads the image. [Overlayed results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGbPY.jpg) (The red is the white part from my result, the grey is the black part from my result. Black/white is from Matlab)

Comment: Are the sizes of these results the same? I think MATLAB pads the output?

Comment: Matlab pads it with a white border, the total image size it makes is 866x796. The matrix it makes is 1023x1023.
Mine has input and results at 512x512

Comment: Isn't that the difference you are seeing? If you crop MATLAB's result to your size, how do they compare?

Comment: The image I originally attached for the Matlab result is the cropped version. I cropped it down to 512. Matlabs looks more to the top left though, while mine is very centered

Comment: I just added an edit about that, how does Matlab pad the image? It looks like mine is very close to the Matlab one when I overlay them.

Comment: Did you use [`xcorr2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html) for the MATLAB result? That result looks surprising...

Comment: Yeah I did xcorr2 on the 2 images, then called imshow on the result.

Comment: If I do `ifft2(fft2(image).*conj(fft2(template)))` I get the same result as you. But do note that you should display with `imshow(result,[])`, you'll get a different view of your result! (the range is not 0-1, so everything that you now see as white actually has many different values).

Comment: I also just tested that and got the same thing. So I guess I just need to tweak my code so that it doesn't scale the result to 0-1. Thanks for the help!